# MUI handle only one of onBlur and onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, material-ui

I'm currently tackling a TypeScript and Material-UI project. My goal is to manage both the onBlur event and the onEnter key press event for a TextField component.

Here's the scenario: I've integrated this text field within a menu. When a user types into the field and then clicks outside the menu, I want to store the entered value using the onBlur event. However, I also need to capture the value when the Enter key is pressed. The issue arises because pressing Enter triggers both the onKeyDown event and the onBlur, resulting in the function being called twice where I save the value.

I've searched online and other stackoverflow posts but haven't found a solution that solves this issue (Maybe because of TS and cannot call with the other event).

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const MyComponent = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const [enterPressed, setEnterPressed] = useState(false);

const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
if (event.key === 'Enter') {
  setEnterPressed(true);
  // Handle saving the value when Enter is pressed
  saveValue();
 }
 };

const handleBlur = () => {
// Check if Enter was pressed, if so, do not save the value again
if (!enterPressed) {
  // Handle saving the value on blur
  saveValue();
}
// Reset the enterPressed state
setEnterPressed(false);
};

const saveValue = () => {
// Save the entered value (you can replace this with your logic)
console.log('Value to save:', value);
// Clear the input or perform any necessary actions
setValue('');
};

return (
<TextField
  value={value}
  onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  label="Enter value"
  variant="outlined"
 />
 );
 };

 export default MyComponent;
```

To handle both the onBlur event and the Enter key press event in a TextField component using TypeScript and Material-UI, you can use a combination of state management and event handling to achieve your goal.

One approach is to use a state variable to keep track of whether the Enter key was pressed. When handling the onKeyDown event, you can set this state accordingly and use it to prevent the onBlur event from triggering when Enter was pressed.